# I have written a simple Javascript closure code but it doesn't run. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am a beginner in Javascript and after few coding practices now I started closures. I have written a simple code where on click of a link which displays sizes the font-size of the document's body must increase respectively. But I don't understand where I am going wrong.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <style>
             body {
             font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
             font-size: 10px;
             background-color: bisque;
             color:black;
             }
          </style>
</head>
       <body>
          <p>HELLO!! I AM CHANGING MY SIZES.</p>
          <a href="#" id="size-12" onclick="changeSize(12)">Size 12</a>
          <a href="#" id="size-14" onclick="changeSize(14)">Size 14</a>
          <a href="#" id="size-16" onclick="changeSize(16)">Size 16</a>
          <script>
             function changeSize(size) {
                   return function () {
                       document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
                   }
               };
          </script>
       </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Your change size is returning a function, just call the style change instead of returning a function.

Answer (score 2):

So as of right now you're returning a function, which you aren't calling-to call the function, change each of the onclicks as so:

`onclick="changeSize(12)()"`

This makes it so changeSize(12) returns the inner function, and then using the second parentheses calls the inner function :)

EDIT: Like others have said, there isn't really need here to return an inner function, and if the contents of the function changeSize() was instead something like

```
function changeSize(size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}
```

it would be much more concise

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: While this works, it's not an optimal solution. Having a function inside a function is overkill here

Comment: While this solves the problem at hand, it completely ignores that the implementation is nonsense.

Comment: It's true, but I figured I should explain why the behavior the user was getting was happening.  I'll edit my solution to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry @Amethystx87 your answer is technically fine -- it answers the question asked. I was more referring to OP :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons to use a function generated from a closure is to create a function that "freezes" a more general function with some particular set of parameters. Though it's true that you could "fix" your issue by changing the handler attributes with an additional `()` at the end, there's really no point using a function-maker function if that's what you're going to end up doing.

Instead, you can make a set of pre-created functions to use from your HTML:

```
      <script>
         function changeSize(size) {
               return function () {
                   document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
               }
           };

         var size12 = changeSize(12);
         var size14 = changeSize(14);
         var size16 = changeSize(16);
      </script>
```

Now your HTML can use those prepared functions:

```
      <a href="#" id="size-12" onclick="size12()">Size 12</a>
      <a href="#" id="size-14" onclick="size14()">Size 14</a>
      <a href="#" id="size-16" onclick="size16()">Size 16</a>
```

Comment: Also: if you're making a clickable page element that only runs some JavaScript code, you really should use a `<button type=button>` element and not an `<a>`.

Comment: It makes more sense to me now. Thanks @Pointy :)